# easy list with beamer?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, easylist

Can we use  in beamer? Is there any efficient way to itemize and sub itemize in beamer?? The following code not working

```
\documentclass[mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}
\author[Nck]{Newbie}
\title[Eco'trics]{Introduction to Statistics and Econometrics}
\subtitle{TA}
\institute[Blah]{Learning Univ}
\subject{Econometrics}

\begin{frame}{Variance and Covariance}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
@\textbf{Def 4.2.1} -
        \begin{align*}
        V(X) &= E[ X - E(X)]^2\\
        &=E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2
        \end{align*}
@ \textbf{Thm 4.2.1} - If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, we have:
            \[
            V(\alpha X  + \beta) = \alpha^2V(X)
            \]
@\textbf{Covariance}, deonoted by $Cov(X,Y)$ or $\sigma_{xy}$ is a measure of the relationship between two random variables X and Y and is defined as : 
@@ $Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))] = E(XY) - E(X) E(Y)$

\end{easylist}
\end{frame}
```

Also whats the use of Subject? Does it appear anywhere on the beamer?

Comment: In your code you are two \begin{document}. For use of the easylist see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures, but in beamer is more appropriate to use itemize/enumerate/description as the provided by beamer package

Comment: You should place the meta data (`\author`, `\title`, `\subtitle`, `\institute`, `\subject`, ...) in the document preamble and then check the output PDF properties to see where they are used.

Comment: yes, i read this. Thank You @Zarko!! But I use itemize so much that I was wondering if easy list could be integrated with beamer!!

Comment: @Werner - Cool! :)

Comment: @Nck: From p 3 of the [`easylist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/easylist) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf): "Every sequence of `§`’s
must terminate with a space, otherwise numbers won’t be printed." Here § represents the character used to denote an "`\item`" - `@` in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `easylist` package uses catcode tricks, which don't work properly with `beamer`'s usual frame processing code. (Same as `verbatim`.)

To fix this (but slow down the output slightly), write

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{...}
```

instead. Fixing the original example for typos and simplifying it a bit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Variance and Covariance}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
@ \textbf{Def 4.2.1} -
        \begin{align*}
        V(X) &= E[ X - E(X)]^2\\
        &=E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2
        \end{align*}
@ \textbf{Thm 4.2.1} - If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, we have:
            \[
            V(\alpha X  + \beta) = \alpha^2V(X)
            \]
@ \textbf{Covariance}, deonoted by $Cov(X,Y)$ or $\sigma_{xy}$ is a measure of the relationship between two random variables X and Y and is defined as : 
@@ $Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))] = E(XY) - E(X) E(Y)$

\end{easylist}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```