# How to modify itemize in beamer with conditional spacing between items depending on nested sublists?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to modify the itemize command of the *beamer* package so that it adds some amount of vertical space before each item for which the previous item contains a nested sublist. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1.1
        \item 1.2
    \end{itemize}
    \item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 2.1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2.1.1
            \item 2.1.2
        \end{itemize}
        \item 2.2
    \end{itemize}
    \item 3
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 3.1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 3.1.1
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like the list in the example to be typeset like this:

```
1
1.1
1.2
<-- space here
2
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
<-- space here
2.2
<-- space here
3
3.1
3.1.1
```

An important requirement is that there should be no space *after* the entire environment. The following small "algorithm" should clarify what I'm trying to achieve:

- Maintain a variable **lastItemLevel**, initially set to 0.
- When starting an item, if the current item's level is smaller than **lastItemLevel**, add some vertical space; and, in any case, reset **lastItemLevel** to the current item's level.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the internals of LaTeX and *beamer* sufficiently well to implement this idea.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before and after:

[image][image]

The only thing you have to know is `\@itemdepth`, the (TeX)counter storing the current level. By the way, if you have so many `itemize`'s, would you like to use [easylist with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/easy-list-with-beamer)?

```
\documentclass[handout,draft]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2.1
            \item 2.2
        \end{itemize}
        \item 3
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 3.1
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 3.1.1
                \item 3.1.2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \item 4
    \end{itemize}
    outside itemize
\end{frame}
\makeatletter
\newcount\lastItemLevel\lastItemLevel1
\let\olditem\item
\def\item{%
    \ifnum\@itemdepth<\lastItemLevel\vspace*{1em}\fi%
    \global\lastItemLevel\@itemdepth%
    \olditem}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2.1
            \item 2.2
        \end{itemize}
        \item 3
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 3.1
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 3.1.1
                \item 3.1.2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \item 4
    \end{itemize}
    outside itemize
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```